# percentage of From Stage record count in Salesforce Opportunity History matrix report

Tags: reporting, formula

How can I get the percentages in this screen shot to work?:

[image: Record Count Percentage]

Here's my custom summary formula:

```
RowCount/PARENTGROUPVAL(RowCount, FROM_OPPORTUNITY_STAGE_NAME, COLUMN_GRAND_SUMMARY)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `RowCount/PARENTGROUPVAL(RowCount, OWNER_NAME, STAGE_NAME)`

[image]

Let me know if it's working.